# Use cakephp 2 users table for login into cakephp 3 application

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Want to run two applications, one in CakePHP 2 and another in CakePHP 3 with same database.

How can I point cake 3 to use cake 2 authentication component?

Comment: Why do you want to use C2 auth which you can use C3 auth? There is no change in DB for C3

Comment: @urfusion I have rest api setup in cakephp 3 and cakephp 2 is web application i want to login though from api (cake3) into cakephp 2 db credential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CakePHP 3 `AuthComponent` with your Users table from CakePHP 2.

You may have to tweak the Auth settings a bit and change the password hashing algorithm which defaults to `DefaultPasswordHasher` in Cake 3.

Comment: Can i use reverse in CakePHP 2 `AuthComponent` in CakePHP 3?

Comment: Yes, why not? To be more clear: You do not have to use the AuthComponent of the other Cake System – just use the database/Users table and if necessary tweak the Auth settings and/or PasswordHasher.